# What to expect for fitness and strength losses given x amount of days of rest?

Tags: strength, training, rest

After training off and on (mostly on) for about a year, I recently took a break from the gym and didn't exercise at all aside from gentle walking for close to 3 weeks.  When I returned, it seems I lost a fair bit of fitness and strength.  I dropped down on bench press reps at the previous weight, pull up reps, and really dropped on running endurance and sustained speed (from 40 min at avg 8min/mi to 16 min at 8:30 and I had to stop!).

It's pretty disheartening, as it feels I have taken nearly six months step backward after just three weeks.  (But I admit, I have not tracked things carefully enough to really quantify it.)

So, **What (evidence based) "rules" can one rely on to reasonably predict fitness losses after a break of x amount of days?**  This should take into account things like age, sex, type and intensity of training, break duration, and whatever else is applicable.  I want to know because I want to know if this recent loss is in the normal range, as well as how I need to plan ahead in terms of future vacations in which I am away from my gym.

Comment: It's discouraging, but you should find that you'll get it back quickly if you start exercising again. It won't take six months to regain six months' worth of previous progress.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Practical Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0976805413) (p. 148) the continuum of adaption persistence (from most persistent to least persistent) is:

- Hypertrophy
- Strength
- Power
- Technique
- Muscular Endurance
- Cardiovascular Endurance

> Significant loss of VO2 max (cardiovascular endurance) can occur in a
>   matter of days, whereas the significant decay of added muscle mass
>   (hypertrophy) may take many weeks or months following the cessation of
>   training.